# Adding delay to clock for razor flip flop

Tags: razor, verilog

i am doing a project in vedic

Heading

multiplier wherein i have to use razor flip flop where i have a main clock to one flip flop and another delayed clock to another flip flop and compare .can anybody say how to give to delay to clock # is not working.delay must meet setup time of both flip flops

Comment: Well, I didn't know what a Razor Flip-Flop was, but I have a some idea now. `#` is how Verilog does delays, so, to answer your question, we need to see some code.

Comment: I am guessing you need to generate the clock and delayd clock as stimulus for your block, and not to synthesis them?

Comment: @MatthewTaylor `#` only delays in simulation, typically. Any attempts to add delays between physical FPGA elements would require specialized constraints and additional clock-handling circuitry. Also, Razor does have an electronics interpretation: See [1](http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~taustin/papers/IEEEMICRO05-Razor.pdf) , [2](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/login.jsp?tp=&arnumber=1253179&url=http%3A%2F%2Fieeexplore.ieee.org%2Fxpls%2Fabs_all.jsp%3Farnumber%3D1253179), and [3](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/wi09/cse240c/Slides/17_Razor_and_ReCycle.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Razor proposal, a Razor flip-flop consists of a pair of a normal edge-triggered flip-flop, and a "shadow latch" triggered by a delayed version of the clock. You can implement this by using a PLL to shift the clock by a known phase shift (assuming the clock's frequency is within the range of the PLL's VCO, this is straightforward). The shadow latch may be a level sensitive latch as is available on some FPGA hardware, or you may use a particularly late edge trigger and sacrifice some of the benefits of the Razor design in order to work with your available storage/register resources.

Comment: thank you for your help  done it in core generator pll_adv

Comment: @kabilan If this answer answered your question, please consider marking it with the checkmark to notify future visitors searching for the same question that it was solved here.